# Incorrect Query Result in ZF2

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

I have a query in a model:

```
public function loadPerform(){
    $select = $this->select()
              ->from(array('p' => $this->_tables['performance']))
              ->join(array('phc' => $this->_tables['perf_has_component']), 'phc.performance_id=p.performance_id', array('*'), 'left');
    //echo str_replace('"','',$select->getSqlString())."<br />";
   return $this->fetchAll($select);
}
```

The result is:

```
Array([0]=>Array(
[performance_id]=>
[title]=>Performance11
[description]=>haha
[create_dtm]=>2016-04-0500: 14: 54
[create_by]=>90141063
[phc_id]=>
[last_update_dtm]=>
[update_by]=>
))
```

It works, but it didn't show `performance_id` in result. What's wrong with my query?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please modify your query:

```
$select = $this->select()
              ->from(array('p' => $this->_tables['performance']),array('performance_id'))
              ->join(array('phc' => $this->_tables['perf_has_component']), 'phc.performance_id=p.performance_id', array('*'), 'left');
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanation on why this would work and why the code in the question does not give the desired result.

Comment: Please refer this page: http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.db.sql.html